# Make textbox determine javascript variable

Tags: javascript, variables, button, textbox

I need a javascript variable to be whatever is entered into a textbox when a button is pressed.

Basically, if somebody enters "bubbles" into the textbox and then clicks the button that says submit, I need "var Item" to be bubbles. How to I make that function?

I want an if statement if possible, so something like

```
    var Item = getElementById(whatever the id of the textbox content it)
    function Thing() {
    if {
    getElementById(whatever the id of the textbox content it) = bubbles;
    document.open(P2.html);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the value like this:

```
<script>
    function getValue(){
        var value = document.getElementBydId("textbox").value;
    }
</script>
<textarea id="texbox"></textarea>
<button onclick="getValue()">
```